# Consulta SQL Server [FULL JOIN o FULL OUTER JOIN]

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo 3 tablas, `tblUsuario`, `tblMenu` y `tblRolPermisos`;

En `tblUsuario` tengo:

```
.......................................................................  
IdUsuario, Usuario, IdRol  
.......................................................................  
1, 'admin', 1  
2, 'guest', 2  
.......................................................................
```

En `tblMenu` tengo 4 menus:

```
.......................................................................  
IdMenu | Titulo  
.......................................................................  
1, Inicio  
2, Configuración  
3, Catalogos  
4, Usuarios  
.......................................................................
```

en `tblRolPermisos` especifico que acceso a menús y permisos tiene cada rol, ejemplo:

```
.......................................................................  
IdPermiso | IdRol | IdMenu | AccesoMenu | PermisoCrear | PermisoBorrar | PermisoActualzar
.......................................................................

//El IdRol **#1** tiene acceso a todo:

1, **1**, 1, true, true, true, true  
2, **1**, 2, true, true, true, true  
3, **1**, 3, true, true, true, true  
4, **1**, 4, true, true, true, true

//Mientras que el IdRol **#2** solo tiene acceso a algunas partes

5, **2**, 1, true, true, false, true  
6, **2**, 4, true, true, false, true
```

Lo que necesito, es hacer una consulta que obtenga todos los menus y permisos, y que por un `where` me filtre estos por `IdRol`; el problema es que si los filtro solo por `IdRol`, solo me trae algunos, no todos. Me explico: Si filtro por el `IdRol = 2`, solo me traerá 2 registros; sin embargo, como dije, necesito que me muestre todos los menús y me salga `NULL` si es que no existe registro para ese `RolPermiso`.

Aquí un ejemplo de lo que necesito filtrando el IdRol por **2**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

La consulta que trate hacer:

```
SELECT
    MP.IdRolPermiso,
    R.IdRol,
    M.IdMenu,
    M.Titulo,
    AccesoMenu = CONVERT(BIT, ISNULL(RP.AccesoMenu, 0)),
    PermisoCrear = CONVERT(BIT, ISNULL(RP.PermisoCrear, 0)),
    PermisoActualizar = CONVERT(BIT, ISNULL(RP.PermisoActualizar, 0)),
    PermisoBorrar = CONVERT(BIT, ISNULL(RP.PermisoBorrar, 0))
FROM
    tblMenu M
    FULL OUTER JOIN tblRolPermisos RP ON M.IdMenu = RP.IdMenu
    FULL OUTER JOIN tblRol R ON RP.IdRol = R.IdRol
WHERE
    R.IdRol = 2
```

Comment: Edita por favor y agrega la consulta que trataste

Comment: @gbianchi Sí, hay una tabla tblRol que tiene todos los Roles

Comment: @Aprendiz ya la agregue, a ver si les sirve

Comment: que seria MP en esa consulta? no hay una tabla MP... debe ser M?

Comment: @gbianchi MP es RP, se me fue el dedo al editar el codigo, sin embargo aun poniendo RP el resultado es el mismo, la tabla Rol no viene siendo relevante, solo es un catalogo, IdRol | Nombre, el dato que importa es el IdRol, y quiero filtrar este mismo, no quiero mostrar el Nombre.

Comment: @gbianchi igual ya la agregue, creo que se entiende mas asi

Answer (score 2):

Lo que vos buscas se soluciona seleccionando todos los IdMenu de tu tabla tblMenu, y solo aquellos tblRolPermisos que existan..

Para hacer esto, hacemos un left join (que traiga todo lo que esta a la izquierda) entre las tablas tblMenu y tblRolPermisos

```
SELECT
    RP.IdRolPermiso,
    RP.IdRol,
    M.IdMenu,
    M.Titulo,
    AccesoMenu = CONVERT(BIT, ISNULL(RP.AccesoMenu, 0)),
    PermisoCrear = CONVERT(BIT, ISNULL(RP.PermisoCrear, 0)),
    PermisoActualizar = CONVERT(BIT, ISNULL(RP.PermisoActualizar, 0)),
    PermisoBorrar = CONVERT(BIT, ISNULL(RP.PermisoBorrar, 0))
FROM
    tblMenu M
    LEFT JOIN tblRolPermisos RP ON M.IdMenu = RP.IdMenu
WHERE
    RP.IdRol = 2 or ISNULL(RP.IdRol)
```

---

Edicion:

Si no se agrega el isnull al where, no va a traer todos los registros necesarios porque los va a terminar filtrando el where

Answer (score 1):

Dado que tenes una tabla de roles y de menú, yo iniciaría haciendo el producto cartesiano (`cross join`) de ambas tablas. Eso me asegura tener todos los registros de menú para el rol que me interesa, algo como:

```
select M.idMenu, R.idRol
  from tblMenu M
       cross join tblRol R
 where R.idRol = 2;
```

Esto me va a devolver la base para hacer el siguiente join:

```
idMenu idRol
====== =====
1      2
2      2
3      2
4      2
```

Finalmente, sobre esto, haría un `left join` a la tabla `tblRolPermisos` para obtener el resto de datos:

```
select M.idMenu, R.idRol, RP.IdPermiso, RP.AccesoMenu, RP.PermisoCrear, RP.PermisoBorrar, RP.PermisoActualzar
  from tblMenu M
       cross join tblRol R
       left join tblRolPermisos RP on RP.idMenu = M.idMenu and RP.idRol = R.idRol
 where R.idRol = 2;
```

No usaría `IsNull`, dado que veo que quieres nulos en caso de no existir el registro.